# Use proxy with authentication and https

Tags: python-3.x, curl, proxy

I am using curl for connecting through proxy to https webpage, concretely this command:

```
curl --proxy https://PROXY_IP:80 -PROXY_USERNAME:PROXY_PASSWORD -k -L https://www.rotogrinders.com
```

Do you know how to do the same in Python 3? I tried request library, but it didn't work, probably because https through proxy is bugged in requests.

EDIT: requests code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

class Downloader:
    def get_page(self, url):
        proxies = self.get_proxies()
        auth = HTTPProxyAuth("PROXY_USERNAME", "PROXY_PASSWORD")

        r = requests.get(url, proxies = proxies, auth = auth)
        return r.text

    def get_proxies(self):
        return {"https" : "PROXY_IP:80"}


downloader = Downloader()
downloader.get_page("https://www.rotogrinders.com")
```

This code returns following exception:
`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.rotogrinders.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',)))`

Comment: Can you show the code you tried using `requests`?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question.

Comment: Which version of requests are you using? The broken HTTPS proxy support was supposedly fixed in `2.0.0` due to the [underlying `urllib3` bug](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/50) being fixed.

Comment: I am using version 2.9.1 of requests.